# Pass Struct with an array and Index to access to Thread

Tags: c, multithreading

For a prime factorization project, I need to pass a struct and a number (from the command line) to a thread. The below code is what I have so far. The factorization works fine, the problem is that the index passed to the thread isn't being passed in order, so the results vary, often storing data in the same index in a subsequent thread. Anyone know how to guarantee which index the thread will access, or a better way of implementing this? Each thread has to store their data in a struct so that the main thread can print all the data at the end, once all threads have closed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Initialize Constants
#define MAX_ARGS 25
#define MAX_PRIMES 10
#define SMALLEST_ARG 2

// Define Struct
struct PrimeData {
    int index;
    int num_to_fact[MAX_ARGS];
    int primes[MAX_ARGS][MAX_PRIMES];
};

// Declare Functions
void* factor (void*);

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize Struct Variables
    struct PrimeData data;
    struct PrimeData* data_addr = &data;
    data.index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; i++)
        data.num_to_fact[i] = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_PRIMES; j++)
            data.primes[i][j] = -1;
    }

    // Check for arguments
    if (argc <= 1)
        printf("Usage: ./p3 <number to factor>...\n");
    else {
        // Initialize Thread Handler list
        pthread_t threads[argc - 1];

        // Create a Thread per Argument
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            // Update shares structure
            data.index = i - 1;
            data.num_to_fact[i - 1] = atoi(argv[i]);            

            // Create thread
            pthread_create(&threads[i - 1], NULL, factor, (void*)data_addr);
        }

        // Tell main to wait for threads to terminate
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
            pthread_join(threads[i - 1], NULL);
    }

    // Iterate through struct
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; i++) {
        if (data.num_to_fact[i] == -1)
            break;
        printf("%d: ", data.num_to_fact[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_PRIMES; j++) {
            if (data.primes[i][j] == -1)
                break;
            printf("%d ", data.primes[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Terminate
    return 0;
}

// The factor() function
void* factor(void* data)
{
    struct PrimeData* d = (struct PrimeData*)data;
    int index = d->index;
    int n = d->num_to_fact[index];
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 2;
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            while (n % i == 0) {
                d->primes[index][counter] = i;
                n = n / i;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thread is not just a function, it has it own execution context which is out of control of your main function. This mean you are running function factor multiple time without specific order to start and finish.

When you create a Thread per Argument and change your reference data content (index) which each Thread need to use, You also cause a problem for those threads that need to access data content.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one 'struct PrimeData data;', so there is no point in signaling the address of it in the pthread_create call. The messy way would be to globalize 'PrimeData' so the threads have access to it, array-ize the index: 'int index[MAX_ARGS];', load it with 0,1,2,3.. etc and then pass the address of the required index to each thread, eg '&data_addr[i-1]'.

It might be clearer if you accepted that C arrays are indexed from zero and so get rid of a lot of those [i-1] things.

Comment: The problem is the thread also needs a number given from the command line. The first argument is the generic call, all subsequent arguments from the user starts with 1, hence the i-1 and all that. Basically, each thread needs a number from the command line, and then store that number plus the prime factors into a struct, and then the main thread prints all the information out. I know how to pass a struct to the thread, however, if i pass the struct, then i can't pass the argument from the command line. Unless i place that into the struct first, unless there's a way to pass both.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using a mutex. Kind of odd, we do not cover mutexes until the next chapter. I eventually stumbled upon an article explaining that when you use multithreading where each thread is accessing a shared memory location (my struct in this case) then you have to use a mutex control the index:

```
// At the start of the program, before main
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int _index = -1;

// first three lines of the factor function
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
_index++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define Struct
struct PrimeData {
    int num_to_fact[MAX_ARGS];
    int primes[MAX_ARGS][MAX_PRIMES];
};

typedef struct Wrapper {
    int index;
    struct PrimeData *data;
} Wrapper;

...

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    // ...
    // Define wrappers
    Wrapper wrappers[argc-1];

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        wrappers[i-1].index = i;
        wrappers[i-1].data = &data;
        //...
        pthread_create(&threads[i - 1], NULL, factor, wrappers + i - 1);
    }
    // ...
}

void *factor(void *wrapper)
{
    Wrapper *w = (Wrapper *) wrapper;
    struct PrimeData* d = w->data;
    int index = w->index;   
    // ...
}
```